# Missing roads from OpenStreetMap data with osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osmfilter

I am currently trying to extract road networks from OpenStreetMap dumps downloaded on [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/). I am using the following osmosis (version 0.45) command to extract roads:

```
osmosis \
--rbf input.osm.pbf \
--tf reject-relations \
--tf accept-ways highway=motorway,motorway_link,trunk,trunk_link,primary,primary_link,secondary,secondary_link,tertiary,tertiary_link,unclassified,residential \
--tf reject-ways highway=construction \
--lp --wb output_roads.osm.pbf
```

This should return a file containing all car roads except service roads.

However, some (and sometimes a lot of) roads are missing. I have tried this command on 3 input files:

- "Midi-Pyrénées" French region: the road network seems almost complete. The attribute table contains 72010 elements.
- all of France: a lot of roads are missing. The attribute table contains only 65803 elements (less than a single region). All types of highways are impacted: primary to residential. There is no any obvious pattern for the missing roads.
- all of Europe: almost all roads are missing. The attribute table contains 62092 elements (less than all of France...).

I guess there is some limitation I am not aware of, either on the osmosis command or on the output file. What am I doing wrong here?

This may be unrelated but I have tried using the `--used-node` option in order to reduce the size of the output files, but this always generates an error (`org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to create object stream writing to temporary file null.`). I have no idea why.

Update 29/08/2018: I also tried using `osmfilter` (`input.o5m --keep="highway=" > output_roads.osm`), with the same results. I tried osmosis and osmfilter both on Windows 7 and Debian 9.5 (both 64 bits).

Comment: So consider using `--tf accept-ways highway=* \\`, in your example you don't take into account all the type of road.

Comment: Hi @obchardon, your suggestion gives almost the sames results (65356 elements for France). I should add that all types of highway are impacted (all lot of primary roads are missing).

Comment: Are you running a recent version of osmosis? And do you have enough free space on disk?

Comment: @AndreJ: I am running osmosis 0.45 and I have more than 100 Go of available space, which should be enough.

Comment: Sounds ok. have you tried `--rb`?

Comment: @AndreJ just tried it, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe the people at https://help.openstreetmap.org/ have a solution to your problem.

Comment: `your suggestion gives almost the sames results (65356 elements for France)` : This caught my attention : 65356 is exactly a 16 bit limitation of value (2^16), like an Int16 max value. I guess that must be the limitation you are looking for. Maybe you can't get more than 2^16 max features.

Comment: @gisnside Yes, I also thought of something like that. But I didn't find where this limitation comes from.

Comment: I looked a bit at the osmosis ref page for the --wb tag [wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.45#--write-pbf_.28--wb.29) but I didn't find exactly where it could occur. You might have a look and try and tweak some options. (ex : batchlimit ?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to change some options but it didn't change much.

Comment: 65356 is a red herring, 2^16 is 65536.

Comment: Try performing this on a smaller area, perhaps Corisca, Crete, Corfu or another island and see how that works. If it works then your scripts are memory bound.  It is probably the number of nodes your are trying to store rather than the number of actual roads which will waiver depending on total nodes. Can you do the extract by Department?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using the HOT site to download OSM data. You can download data for a specific location or even draw a boundary for an area. and download only the road.

https://export.hotosm.org/en/v3/exports/new/describe

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question of how to do this in osmosis, but if the answer is you can't do it in osmosis and can in HOT, then I think you need at least to show how to do comparable queries to those in the question with number of results returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try including all roads, for example use:

```
osmosis \
--rbf input.osm.pbf \
--tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node \
--wb output_roads.osm.pbf
```